# how to use "not in" in case command - bash

Tags: bash, switch-statement

I tried to use "not in" in case command -

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR="A-1"

case "$VAR" in
        !("^A-.*[0-9]"))
        echo "yes";;
esac
```

and got this error:
`Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")`.

I got the same error when I used:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR="A-1"

case "$VAR" in
        !(^A-.*[0-9]$)) echo "yes";;
esac
```

Comment: Define the case it's not in, then use `*)` to define the catchall case, which will essentially be the "not". Otherwise case does not support "not"

Comment: Yes, I tried with "if" condition and it worked, thanks

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use extended glob pattern syntax; to do this, you must first enable extended globs with `shopt -s extglob`.